# Undefined Index in laravel

Tags: laravel, indexing, undefined

[image]

I have set a default value (0) for expert and when I check expert checkbox which saves 1 in the expert column in the database. but when I do not check that box it returns error of undefined index.

[image]

Comment: Show some sample code you are trying

Comment: Its not error from sql.. its an error from php code. You have set default value for sql table column.. So you have to check whether the values isset or not

Comment: Show us your code.  Screenshots are not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the checkbox is checked means it will give values otherwise it wont give any value

Try this

```
(isset($data['expert']) ? $data['expert'] : '0');
```

Comment: If(isset($_POST["expert"])){


            return User::create([
                my data 
                'expert'=>$_POST["expert"]

            ]);
        }
        else{
            return User::create([
                my data
                ]);

        }

Answer (score 0):

If(isset($_POST["expert"])){

```
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'dob' => $data['dob'],
            'expert'=>$_POST["expert"]

        ]);
    }
    else{
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'dob' => $data['dob']
            ]);

    }
```